# Trying to find the regex for pretty URLs

Tags: javascript, regex, grunt-contrib-connect

I have a website structure like this:

```
/docs/one_of_the_resources/one-of-the-resources.html
/docs/a_complete_different_resource/a-complete-different-resource.html
```

I want to get rid of all sub-folders in the url and get this:

```
/one-of-the-resources.html
/a-complete-different-resource.html
```

Sub-folders should not be affected:

```
/docs/one_of_the_resources/assets/*
```

The folder name is always the same as the html file just dashes are swapped with underline and of course there is no suffix.

I'm using [grunt-contrib-rewrite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-connect-rewrite) and grunt-connect.

Can't wrap my head around it. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negated character class

```
/\/[^/]+$/
```

- `[^/]+` Matches anything other than a `/`. The quantifier `+` ensures one or more characters.
- `$` Anchors the regex at the end of the string.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rW2nD9/1)

**Example**

```
string = "/docs/one_of_the_resources/one-of-the-resources.html";
console.log(string.match(/\/[^/]+$/)[0]);
// => one-of-the-resources.html
```